# How to compare multiple objects in a JSON response using groovy script

Tags: json, groovy

I was working on an API that was provided to me to learn groovy scripting for asserting a JSON response.

The API is

> https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2019-06-10&end_date=2019-06-16&api_key=*************

You can get the key from here: https://api.nasa.gov/index.html#apply-for-an-api-key

This is a small part of the json response:

```
    "element_count": 69,
       "near_earth_objects":    {
          "2019-05-10":       [
                      {
                "links": {"self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/3842596?api_key=******"},
                "id": "3842596",
                "neo_reference_id": "3842596",
                "name": "(2019 KM2)",
                "nasa_jpl_url": "http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3842596",
                "absolute_magnitude_h": 25.762,
                "estimated_diameter":             {
                   "kilometers":                {
                      "estimated_diameter_min": 0.0187134981,
                      "estimated_diameter_max": 0.0418446538
                   },
                   "meters":                {
                      "estimated_diameter_min": 18.7134980647,
                      "estimated_diameter_max": 41.8446537694
                   },
                   "miles":                {
                      "estimated_diameter_min": 0.011628025,
                      "estimated_diameter_max": 0.0260010544
                   },
                   "feet":                {
                      "estimated_diameter_min": 61.3959929905,
                      "estimated_diameter_max": 137.2856138729
                   }
                },
                "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": false,
                "close_approach_data": [            {
                   "close_approach_date": "2019-05-10",
                   "close_approach_date_full": "2019-May-10 19:38",
                   "epoch_date_close_approach": 1557517080000,
                   "relative_velocity":                {
                      "kilometers_per_second": "2.5687395339",
                      "kilometers_per_hour": "9247.4623220529",
                      "miles_per_hour": "5746.0134633889"
                   },
                   "miss_distance":                {
                      "astronomical": "0.0830780649",
                      "lunar": "32.3173672461",
                      "kilometers": "12428301.552761763",
                      "miles": "7722588.4836998094"
                   },
                   "orbiting_body": "Earth"
                }],
                "is_sentry_object": false
             },
```

How can you assert that is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid is false when astronomical miss_distance is greater than 0.05 from the above API for each object(in this case each meteor)

I know how to parse the response using JsonSlurper but I can't figure out how to just compare within each object. Sorry for the poor wording as I am new to groovy and json.

I tried the following but still no luck

```
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
    def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
    def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
    obj.near_earth_objects.each{
        date,objects->objects.each{
            Object neo = it
            neo.close_approach_data.each{
                if((it.miss_distance.astronomical as Double)>0.05){
                    assert (neo.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid == false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

error that I got:

```
   assert (neo.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid == false) | | | | true                                                                 
   false [absolute_magnitude_h:21.1, close_approach_data: 
   [[close_approach_date:2019-05-10, close_approach_date_full:2019-May-10 
   16:45, epoch_date_close_approach:1557506700000, miss_distance: 
   [astronomical:0.2259243576, kilometers:33797802.678078312, 
   lunar:87.8845751064, miles:21000980.7557402256], orbiting_body:Earth, 
   relative_velocity:[kilometers_per_hour:61066.4765518526, 
   kilometers_per_second:16.9629101533, miles_per_hour:37944.3337218998]]], 
   estimated_diameter:[feet:[estimated_diameter_max:1174.9652706022, 
   estimated_diameter_min:525.4604432536], kilometers: 
   [estimated_diameter_max:0.358129403, estimated_diameter_min:0.160160338], 
   meters:[estimated_diameter_max:358.1294030194, 
   estimated_diameter_min:160.1603379786], miles: 
   [estimated_diameter_max:0.2225312253, 
   estimated_diameter_min:0.0995189894]], id:3258077, 
   is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid:true, is_sentry_object:false, links: 
   [self:http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/3258077?api_key=****], name: 
   (2004 UU1), nasa_jpl_url:http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3258077, 
   neo_reference_id:3258077]
```

I should mention that I am doing this on soapui by adding a script assertion

Comment: You shouldn't share your API credentials

Comment: and now provide an example of the json because we can't access the URL

Comment: i updated the post with one object from the Json response. There are multiple dates with multiple objects in each date. Sorry, just recently started using stackoverflow so I may be doing things wrong.

Comment: now explain what do you mean by `no luck`, because your code seems to be ok. there are some notes but it's ok. do you have any error?

Comment: I updated the post with the error. I also mentioned that i was doing a script assertion on soapui

Comment: That is the expected output when an assertion is false.  There *is* a near earth object with a distance that is > 0.05 where it's marked as potentially hazardous

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as far as I can see...

I tweaked your script a bit, and got the same (valid afaict) result...

```
obj.near_earth_objects.each { date, objects ->
  objects.each { neo ->
    if (neo.close_approach_data.find { it.miss_distance.astronomical.toDouble() > 0.05 }) {
      assert !neo.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the post with the error and I tried yours as well but it has the same type of error. I am doing this on soapui as a script assertion. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: that's the assert showing you that the assertion is false

Comment: ah yes. I wasn't thinking straight. Thank you so much.